# a red and green die are rolled. what is the % of getting a sum of 6 given that the green die is odd

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

The answer that the teacher gave us for this problem is 1/6 but I'm having a hard time getting there. This is what I did. The chance of getting an odd in the green die is 3/6 or 1/2.

If the green die ends up being a 1 then the red die must be a 5

If the green die ends up being a 3 then the red die must be a 3

If the green die ends up being a 5 then the red die must be a 1

I found the probability of each scenario.

P(R5 | G1) = P(R5 intersect G1) / P(G1)

I got  P(R5 intersect G1) to be 1/6 * 1/6 and P(G1) = 1/6

After doing the division I get back 1/6.

The other 2 probabilities is also 1/6. I then add up the 3 or 1/6 * 3 which equal 1/2. Can someone explain to me what I did wrong.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you did wrong is to add those three things at the end. You want $P(A\mid B\mbox{ or }C\mbox{ or }D)$ and you calculated it as $P(A\mid B)+P(A\mid C)+P(A\mid D)$. This is not a valid computation.

Instead, if you must use formulas, use $$P(A\mid B\mbox{ or }C\mbox{ or }D)=\frac{P(A\mbox{ and  }(B\mbox{ or }C\mbox{ or }D))}{P(B\mbox{ or }C\mbox{ or }D)}$$

Or more directly, just count outcomes. There are $18$ outcomes where the green die is odd, and you can list the 3 cases where the sum is 6. So $P=\frac{3}{18}$.

Comment: I see what you mean but for A, it can it either 5 3 or 1. Dont you have to consider all the possibilities because according to your equation, A takes on one value.

Comment: A is the _event_ "rolling a total of 6". It consists of three _outcomes_, yes, but the formula for conditional probability holds for events, not just outcomes.

Answer (score 0):

You're over thinking it.  You don't need to know what the green die is, or what the probability of getting that number was.  You just want to know the probability that the red die will equal a given number.

$$\therefore P(r=6-g \mid g \in \{1,3,5\}) = Pr(r=n \mid n\in \{1,3,5\}) = \frac{1}{6}$$